# Nuimberof intersection in a graph

Tags: python, graph, sage

I am doing a project in sagemath, where I have a list like this  [(0, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 0)]. Which creates a graph below and using that graph it calculates the number of intersecting point as 5(marked in purple color)

[image]

How do I count this value without graphing it? or with graphing?

Comment: You know it's possible to draw that graph with 0 crossings, right?

Comment: how are you drawing the lines? There is no referance

Comment: I don't know even how to graph it, but any method is okh

Comment: Why your right side points aren't in order? For a purpose?

Comment: Yes, to get the lines crossing each other. The main goal is to get the number of intersecting lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this quite interesting question. Could you approach problem like this: think your graph points as layers. Let's name them zero to three according to your left side starting dots.

Then loop layers starting from top and check all layers below it. Every line starting below will cross your line if its ending point is higher layer than your lines ending point.

Code would be something like this.

```
lines = [(0,3),(1,2),(2,0),(3,1)] #translated your cordinates.
cross = 0
lines.sort()  # we want order lines so upper starting point is first
for i in range(len(lines)):  #using index here, easier this time.
    my_start = lines[i][0]
    my_end = lines[i][1]
    for line_below in lines[i:]: # loop through lines below
         if line_below[0] == my_start:
              continue # We don't count crossing if we have the same starting point.
         if line_below[1] < my_end: 
           cross += 1 #if end point is higher than my end poi, we'll corss
```

And I'd visualize your starting / ending points like this, not random order on right side:

```
 0                      0
     
      
 1                      1
          

 2                      2 


 3                      3
```

But actually this approach would work no mater how many starting points or ending points you have in your graph. The code doesn't count crossing if the lines meet on starting point or ending point or if two lines are identical (same starting and ending point).

Comment: What could be done to add count the same starting and ending point?

Comment: If you want to cont identical lines (both starting and ending poitns) you need to add another condition under `if line_below[0] == my_start:`. There you can check if ending point is the same then you have identical lines and you can add one cross.

Answer (score 0):

Here in the given code below, L is the List of the second variable.

So for the above question L = [2,3,1,0]

```
def Ans(L):
  NL=[]
  count=0
  for i in range(0,len(L)):
    for j in range(0,len(L)):
      ifL[j]==i:
        NL.append([i,j])
  for i in range(0,len(L)):
    forjinrange(0,i+1):
      if(NL[i][1]<NL[j][1]):
       count=count+1
  returncount
```